# how to update first row on button click

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, eloquent, updates

i want to update a first record status into '2' based on button click.
Here is my code :

```
     public function repay(Request $request,$loanid){

    $obj = DB::table('schdls')
    ->where('schdls.loanid','=',$loanid)
    ->where('schdls.status','=',1)->first();
   
   
        $obj->status='2';
        $obj->save();
   
    return redirect('/home')->with('message','updated');
      }
```

But it says Call to undefined method stdClass::save() error,

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$obj` is null before assigning value on it.

Use `dd/dump/var_dump` function to check the value and the type of `$obj` after getting record from database.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `update(['status' => '2']);` instead of `save()`

```php
DB::table('schdls')
    ->where('status','=',1)->update(['status' => 2]);
```